# Recursive Algorithm for Simplified Nim Game

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

In a simplified game of Nim where two players take turns to take either 1 or 2 stones from a pile of n stones, and the player to take the last stone wins, a bit of thought or experimentation shows that where `n % 3 == 0`, the first player can't win, but for `n % 3 == 1` or `n % 3 == 2`, they can.

I noticed in arriving at the above solution that I was using a recursive thought process, so rather than writing a program that just used the modulo operator, I want to write a recursive version that tells me whether I can win, and also what move to make at each step.

I've made a start with the Python code below, but am stuck on how to print the instruction for how many stones to take at each step. It's possible I've made a big conceptual error in that I haven't considered what player 2 will do at each step - I can't tell if this information is essential of if I can just use the the observations I have already made. Any help completing my program much appreciated.

```
def last_stone(n):
    # Base cases that guarantees player 1 will lose
    if n == 0:
        print("You can't win.")
        return False
    # Base cases that guarantees player 1 will win
    elif n == 1 or n == 2:
        return True
    else:
        return last_stone(n - 3)


for i in range(10):
    print(last_stone(i))
```

Comment: What are you trying to compute here?

Comment: I want to output the sequence of winning moves or the message "you can't win from this position" if that is the case. Right now I'm just computing n % 3 as someone pointed out. I want to recreate the insight that made it clear that was the solution. With 3 stones left, winning is impossible. With 4 stones, I can refer to what happens previously to determine that I should take 1 stone to ensure winning. It may be that I need an argument for "current player" to make this work, but to get player 2 to always make a winning move I need to have already implemented the solution - catch 22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is simple. Player 1 starts the game. The player-1 would always make a move such that he wins it, same applies for player-2 as well.

Now, this of the problem this way.

- n=1 -> Current Player wins!
- n=2 -> Current Player wins!
- n=3 -> Alternate Player wins!
- n=4 -> Current Player wins!
- so on...

So, just swap the players in alternate moves and take the stones optimally.

```
def get_current_player(moves):
    return "1" if moves%2==0 else "2"

def play_game(n,moves):
    if n==1:
        print("Player "+str(get_current_player(moves))+" moves 1 stone and wins!")
    elif n==2:
        print("Player "+str(get_current_player(moves))+" moves 2 stones and wins!")
    else:
        if n%3==0:
            print("Player "+str(get_current_player(moves))+" moves 1 stone")
            moves+=1
            play_game(n-1,moves)
        else:
            if n%3==1:
                #Move 1 stone and make the opponent lose
                print("Player "+str(get_current_player(moves))+" moves 1 stone")
                moves+=1
                play_game(n-1,moves)

            if n%3==2:
                #Move 2 stones and make the opponent lose
                print("Player "+str(get_current_player(moves))+" moves 2 stones")
                moves+=1
                play_game(n-2,moves)



play_game(6,0)
play_game(5,0)
play_game(3,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you hope to achieve through the recursion, right now you are computing `n%3` in an inefficient way.

For the instructions, the first move is to take `n%3` stones. The rest are 3's complement. If the opponent takes `x` the first player takes `3-x` so you will need to know what move the opponent makes to be able to provide instructions.

The recursion makes more sense if you want to be able to generalize to allow a set of allowed moves (say 1, 2, 5, 7). In that setup you need to know if the first player can win if starting from a certain number of stones (in this case is the player who needs to make the move). The solution tries all the moves, if any of them lead to a losing state, the function returns a win otherwise it returns a loss (take an example on paper, it will make more sense).